# what is the better way of develoment report in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services, reports

I having a problem with a development the a report.

Currently this report are development with **Open XML** but it is very complicated and demand much time. I need know if exists a way diferent for development a report what consume data of list of SharePoint 2013 a very few time.

Comment: The answer strongly depends on the complexity of your report and the cardinality of requirements to have it as an OpenXML document.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reporting options that enable you to show Data from SharePoint List like

- Excel Service.
- Performance Point.
- SQL ServerReporting Service [Create SSRS Report from SharePoint 2013 List using Report Builder 3.0](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/12/create-ssrs-report-from-sharepoint-list.html#ixzz4LCoNvADk).
- Power BI.

Also, check the comparison among the above options at

- [comparing-performancepoint-powerview-excel-services-and-reporting-services](https://businessintelligist.com/2012/04/02/comparing-performancepoint-powerview-excel-services-and-reporting-services/)
- [sql-server-reporting-services-vs-performancepoint-services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2737/sql-server-reporting-services-vs-performancepoint-services/)

**So which reporting option should you choose?**

All the above options help you to show data from SharePoint List but Which option should you use? Ther are 6 factors you should be aware of them before deciding to use a specific tool:

- The SharePoint Edition.
- SharePoint Topology.
- The Capability of the tools.
- The Tool License.
- The Client Requirement.
- your knowledge with this tool.

Based on the above factors you can easily decide which tool should you use.